# C# MVC loading audio reference dynamically in foreach loop

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use a `foreach` loop to play an audio `src` by storing a reference to the sound. This works using

```
 <audio controls>
    <source src="~/Sounds/@item.Irish_Tr" id="@item.ID" type="audio/wav" />
 </audio>
```

However, when I try to use a `<button>` or `<image>` it uses the first sound as a `src` for the rest of the list. Is there any way to get this method to work like the audio control method?

```
<audio id="player">
    <source src="~/Sounds/@item.Irish_Tr" id="@item.ID" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>`

The code above won't work correctly when looped because **`ID` attribute in HTML should be unique** hence why your code is only playing the first audio element.

---

To fix this, add a counter during your foreach that you will increment and append that to the `ID` attribute.

```
@{
   // declare count variable before loop starts
   int count = 0;
}

foreach(var i in records){

   <audio id="player@count">
      <source src="~/Sounds/@item.Irish_Tr" id="@item.ID" type="audio/wav" />
   </audio>
   <button onclick="document.getElementById('player@count').play()">Play</button>

   @count++
}
```